# range of number with loop javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I need make a range from 1 to 15 and some kind of reverse.
Currently i using next script:

```
$scope.range = (min, max) ->
  input = []
  i = min
  while i < max
    input.push i
    i += 1
  input
```

so if put `range(1,15)` it will be `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ... 15`

What  i need is in case when `range(10, 3)` it should put `10 11 12 13 14 15 1 2 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is based on understanding that must go to 15 and order must be as shown:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

function range(min, max) {
    var startArr = arr.slice(arr.indexOf(min)),
        endArr = max < arr.length ? arr.slice(0, arr.indexOf(max) + 1) : [];
    return startArr.concat(endArr);
}


range(10, 3);
//[10,11,12,13,14,15,1,2,3]
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anxrsq30/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks but why in case if may `arr = [{id:1, name: 'John'}, {id:2, name: 'Mark'}, {id:3, name: 'Jim'},{id:4, name: 'Bob'} ... ];` it not works?

Comment: Because this is working from array of integers exactly as you showed in question. If you want it to work on array of objects need to clarify criteria

Comment: Thanks, i'll already handle it. Probably i'll should delete my comment, before you answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
range = (min, max) ->
    input = []
    i = max
    while i > min
      input.push i
      i -= 1
    input

console.log(range( 10, 50 ));
```

Thats really simple try to set i = max an then count i down with the condition that i must be greater than min. That's it. Try the code above.

Comment: I have fixed your script indentation. There is still a problem with the range boundaries: you are missing the inclusive lower bound. Could be fixed by looping with a `while i >= min`. And you are giving the boundaries in reverse order.